# Secure REST API and Single Page App by using external OAuth 2 Authorization Code

Tags: authentication, oauth, rest, single-page-app

I am trying to understand how to implement an OAuth 2 Authorization Code flow when having both a single page JS app and a REST API. The aim is to secure access to the REST API by offloading authentication to the OAuth provider.

Currently my flow looks like:

1)

```
+--------------------+               +----------------+
| JS Single Page App | - redirect -> | OAuth Provider | - user enters credentials
+--------------------+               +----------------+
```

2)

```
+----------------+                                   +----------+
| OAuth Provider | - redirect with temporary code -> | REST API |
+----------------+                                   +----------+
```

3)

```
+----------+                                      +----------------+
| REST API | - request access token using code -> | OAuth Provider |
+----------+ <- return access token ------------- +----------------+
```

What should I do now? My current understanding is that I should redirect the user upon receiving the access token to a page that will load the JS single page app again. But should I share the access token with the single page app and use the presence of it to authenticate any request hitting my REST API, or is better to create a separate identifier and maintain a server-side mapping between `new-identifier->access_token`? Either way what would be the best way of transferring whichever identifier to the client? I would prefer not maintain any session and not have the identifier turn up in the URL bar of the redirected page. The only thing I can currently think of would be to create a temporary cookie that the single page app would read and then erase, but somehow that feels a bit clunky.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, and to be very clear, [**OAuth 2 is not an authentication protocol.**](http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/01/problem-with-oauth-for-authentication.html) If you wish to know the identity of the user, there are other protocols designed to solve this problem, such as [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/). If you intend to use OAuth 2 for the purpose of **authorizing** access to your protected resources, continue reading.

To answer your direct question: you appear to be using the [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) flow:

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |   Owner  |
 |          |
 +----------+
      ^
      |
     (B)
 +----|-----+          Client Identifier      +---------------+
 |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI ---->|               |
 |  User-   |                                 | Authorization |
 |  Agent  -+----(B)-- User authenticates --->|     Server    |
 |          |                                 |               |
 |         -+----(C)-- Authorization Code ---<|               |
 +-|----|---+                                 +---------------+
   |    |                                         ^      v
  (A)  (C)                                        |      |
   |    |                                         |      |
   ^    v                                         |      |
 +---------+                                      |      |
 |         |>---(D)-- Authorization Code ---------'      |
 |  Client |          & Redirection URI                  |
 |         |                                             |
 |         |<---(E)----- Access Token -------------------'
 +---------+       (w/ Optional Refresh Token)
```

This flow is optimized for **confidential clients**: clients which can keep a secret from the end-user and any third-party that might be trying to gain access to the protected resources. In the case of a javascript application running in the client's browser, you cannot keep a secret - all the code is there and simply breaking into it with the browser's debugger reveals all the secrets.

Instead, there is the [Implicit Grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2), specifically optimised for clients like yours. The RFC even uses JavaScript running in a browser as its example of a client intended to use this flow.

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |  Owner   |
 |          |
 +----------+
      ^
      |
     (B)
 +----|-----+          Client Identifier     +---------------+
 |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI --->|               |
 |  User-   |                                | Authorization |
 |  Agent  -|----(B)-- User authenticates -->|     Server    |
 |          |                                |               |
 |          |<---(C)--- Redirection URI ----<|               |
 |          |          with Access Token     +---------------+
 |          |            in Fragment
 |          |                                +---------------+
 |          |----(D)--- Redirection URI ---->|   Web-Hosted  |
 |          |          without Fragment      |     Client    |
 |          |                                |    Resource   |
 |     (F)  |<---(E)------- Script ---------<|               |
 |          |                                +---------------+
 +-|--------+
   |    |
  (A)  (G) Access Token
   |    |
   ^    v
 +---------+
 |         |
 |  Client |
 |         |
 +---------+
```

You should read the RFC for details of how this flow works, but the general concept of the flow is to no longer require the use of an authorization code; instead the client is directly given the access code.

This comes with the drawback that when the code is no longer valid, the client must request the resource again - there is no way to "remember" the authorization grant for a client which is unable to keep a secret. This is an intentional decision made by the OAuth authors to improve the security of clients of this nature.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am indeed using the  Authorization Code Grant flow as I have a server-side part of my application. In this case the access_token would never directly be shared with the client so the attack highlighted in the referenced article would not be possible, or so I believe. But regardless, you are absolutely correct in that OAuth2 is not an authentication framework. I will look into using OpenID Connect instead!

Comment: If you run into similar problems getting an OpenID Connect implementation to work, ask a question about it and add a link to it in a comment here - I'll do my best to assist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your scenario correct. If you only want to secure your RESTful API calls from a javascript client with OAuth then Tragedian's answer about the implicit grant type is absolutely correct. This means that you have a clear segregation of UI and data:

- The UI (i.e. JS single page application) can be loaded without any form of authentication/authorization
- The data (i.e. RESTful API calls) are secured with access tokens AFTER beeing authorized by the authorization server

If you have a different scenario please describe it more precisely. You mention something of a backend part of the application which also relies on OAuth and which is capable of storing sensitive data. This would mean that you have, beside the JS single page app, a DIFFERENT client (in OAuth language)...

Comment: Yes, using the implicit grant type is definitely correct, as is using the authorization grant type. They both come with tradeoffs, and in this case I prefer to use the authorization grant one. My question was whether I could share the access token with the client (ui) or whether I had to generate a new identifier. But as Tragedian correctly pointed out, OAuth2 is not meant for authentication, and I should be using OpenID Connect instead.